# How should I nest these async calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Within my code I have a function that depends on the result of an async call to an API endpoint. In order for the function to execute properly it needs to wait for the result of the call. So I've read up on `async` calls and from another Stack Overflow question I read that you should make use of callback functions to enable correct execution.

The code below is my attempt to make use of callbacks to allow my function to run successfully, but it doesn't work and at the moment I think the calls are messed up.

I'm not sure how I need to structure this code, but I first need the `getInstructionType()` call to return its value, then the `GetValidationResult()` call to return its value, and then the `setValidationRowColor()` function needs to execute.

```js
getInstructionType(applicationNumber, function(result) {
  getInstructionValidationResult(applicationNumber, function(type) {
    setValidationRowColor(result);
  });
});

function getInstructionValidationResult(applicationNumber) {
  var url = //-snip-;
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    return data;
  });
}

function getInstructionType(applicationNumber) {
  var url = //-snip-;
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    return data;
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation? See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ on how to continue once a request has finished.

Answer (score 1):

You could add arguments to the functions which you can use as callbacks. Then you can call those when the AJAX request completes, something like this:

```js
getInstructionType(applicationNumber, function(result) {
  getInstructionValidationResult(applicationNumber, function(type) {
    setValidationRowColor(result);
  });
});

function getInstructionValidationResult(applicationNumber, callback) {
  $.get(/*-snip-*/, function(data) {
    // some custom logic to work with the response here...
    callback && callback(data);
  });
}

function getInstructionType(applicationNumber, callback) {
  $.get(/*-snip-*/, function(data) {
    // some custom logic to work with the response here...
    callback && callback(data);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to callbacks (which are completely valid) are promises - which is really just another form or callbacks. Assuming you are using jQuery's $.get, you are already making use of Promises:

```
getInstructionType(applicationNumber, function(result) {
  return getInstructionValidationResult(applicationNumber)
    .then(function() {
      setValidationRowColor(result)
    })
});

function getInstructionValidationResult(applicationNumber) {
  var url = //-snip-;
  return $.get(url)
}

function getInstructionType(applicationNumber) {
  var url = //-snip-;
  return $.get(url)
}
```

Note that all I did was `return` the `$.get` and added a `.then` which accepts your callback inside `getInstructionType`